Relation of $\frac{f}{g}$ to $\frac{f'}{f}-\frac{g'}{g}$ in reverse order.
Suppose $f$ and $g$ have following properties: $f(0)=g(0)=0$, $f(1)=g(1)=1$, $f'(0)=g'(0)=0$, $f''(x)>0, f'''(x)>0, g''(x)>0, g'''(x)>0 \ \forall x\in(0,1)$.
Then I want to show that $f(x)>g(x) \ \forall x\in(0,1) \Rightarrow \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}<\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \ \forall x\in(0,1)$, or to find a counterexample
Alternatively, RHS above simply states that $\frac{f}{g}$ is decreasing on $(0,1)$
This is trivially true in reverse order i.e $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}<\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} \ \forall x\in(0,1) \Rightarrow f(x)>g(x) \ \forall x\in(0,1)$

UPD: there exists a counterexample: $f(x)=-x^{10}+0.5x^9+1.5x^8$, $g(x)=x^8$

Do you want to answer your own question then, if that solves the problem?

There exists a counterexample: $f(x)=−x^{10}+0.5x^{9}+1.5x^{8}, g(x)=x^8$

@RedFive This is a "complete answer to the question", and Igor was invited to do so.

My apologies - I did not see the comment in the review. Withdrawn.
